# How would I add a swipe action in Javascript using Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am interested in using ngMaterial's swipe since I get the warning...

> You are using the ngTouch module. 
>   Angular Material already has mobile click, tap, and swipe support... 
>   ngTouch is not supported with Angular Material!

Problem is for now this element is not under a directive. Instead I currently use angular.element to grab it then using ngTouch publish a global event...

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('gesture', gestures);
```

I know it may not be the `material-way` but I would just like to attach the swipe events manually.

**Update**

This look promising, although undocumented...

```
$mdGesture.register(myElement, 'drag', { minDistance: 20, horziontal: false })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working version

```
function TouchService($mdGesture, $rootScope){
    this.setElement = function (selector) {
        var element = angular.element(selector);
        $mdGesture.register(element,'swipe', { minDistance: 20, horziontal: false });
        element.on("$md.swipeleft", function(){
            $rootScope.$broadcast('gesture', {direction: 'left'});
        });
        element.on("$md.swiperight", function(){
            $rootScope.$broadcast('gesture', {direction: 'right'});
        });
        element.on("$md.swipeup", function(){
            $rootScope.$broadcast('gesture', {direction: 'up'});
        });
        element.on("$md.swipedown", function(){
            $rootScope.$broadcast('gesture', {direction: 'down'});
        });
    };
}
```